# ImageUpload field missing on edit : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'previewType' on string

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload

I have a custom ImageUploader

Issue : When I try to create a new Object, the image field appears and works fine. Image send to my media dir and the name saved in database.
But, when I try to edit the previously created object, my objet has all his fields registered; but the image field is missing

[image: creation]

[image: edit]

Here comes the field in ui component

```
    <field name="image" sortOrder="40" formElement="imageUploader">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">miseenavant</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Cpy_MiseEnAvant/image-preview</item>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Mise En Avant Image</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <required>false</required>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <imageUploader>
                <settings>
                    <required>false</required>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="mev/image/upload"/>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
                    <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>mev_image/upload</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                </settings>
            </imageUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

It seems to be related to my dataprovider

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = [];
    if($id = $this->request->getParam('id')) {
        $mev = $this->mevFactory->create()->load($id);
        $data[$id] = $mev->getData();
    }
    try {
        if(isset($data[$id])){
            $currentStore = $this->storeManager->getStore();
            $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $data[$id]['image'] = array($mediaUrl.$this->mevHelper::MEV_MEDIA_DIRECTORY.$data[$id]['image']);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Looks like i'm sending an array as image when it should be an object probably, cause I see this error in console :

> file-uploader.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property
> 'previewType' on string
> 'http://mywebsite/media/mev_image/upload/60d2f7eb55bd8.png

Edit : There is is the best I can do digging :/

[image: edit-2]

```
$this->image->prepareDataSource(
    [
        'initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath' => 'mev_image/upload',
        'name' => $data[$id]['image'],
        'file' => $data[$id]['image'],
        'previewType' => 'image',
        'type' => 'image/png',
        'path' => $mediaUrl.$this->mevHelper::MEV_MEDIA_DIRECTORY,
        'url' => $mediaUrl.$this->mevHelper::MEV_MEDIA_DIRECTORY.$data[$id]['image']
    ]
);
$data[$id]['image'] = array($this->image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass image array that contains image url,name.
For passing it to ui component you can use dataprovider

```
<argument name=""class"" xsi:type=""string"">Namespace\Modulen\Model\Modelname\DataProvider</argument>
```

pass array like below.

```
$categoryData['image'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('image');
$categoryData['image'][0]['url'] = $category->getImageUrl();
```

for reference you can look

```
vendor\magento\Magento_Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php
```

[Magento 2 ui component image upload](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/)

Comment: Forgot to update the issue but it's indeed how i manage to did it more or less with may be some different data, but, going with an array is the way.